# Creating object with function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object, express

Hello guys I would like to know how to create an object in node.js with function inside them. Can you give me some examples on how to do this or can you provide me any links guys? I hope you can help me in my problem because I'm just new to node.js.

Comment: Have you tried working through any JavaScript tutorials?

Comment: Please research before asking (or simply [learn javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/contents.html)), and then explain your [problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are treated just like other objects in Javascript, and can be assigned as properties of an object.

For example:

```
var foo = {
    someFunction: function(someArg) {
        // Do something
    }
};

// or add one to an existing object:
foo.anotherFunction = function() {
    // Do something else
};

// Then actually call it:
foo.someFunction("blah");
```

There is nothing Node-specific about this, this is just a detail of the Javascript programming language. There are lots of good books and tutorials out there, and I would suggest the thorough (but log) "[Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)" page from MDN which covers this topic and more.

Comment: Thanks adam. I'll try that. My task is to create an object --> json. I'try to do this. :)

Comment: You cannot serialize functions into json (unless you stringify them and eval them? gross...), what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yeah. i'm using stringify in node :)